# Adding the tag values for packages

Tags: enterprise-architect

In EA there is a tag tab for packages.So from EA we can create the tag and add it to the packages.Now We want to create the tag values from addin and add it to the packages.For creating tagged values for EA.Element we have API

```
Element.TaggedValues.AddNew
```

but for packages we don't have this option.So how can we create the tagged values for packages through addin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A package has a corresponding

```
Package.Element
```

Use that to place your tagged value for the package:

```
Package.Element.TaggedValues.Addnew("name", "notes")
```